# Biopython install error anaconda on windows

Tags: python, anaconda, biopython

from c:/users/me/anaconda3/scripts I `pip install biopython`but it fails with the following errors:
`c:\users\steph\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(243): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

Confusingly, I do have a pyconfig.h in c:\users\steph\anaconda3\include. Cannot find what an exit status 2 is either...

Comment: I think you should be using anaconda (`conda`?) to install biopython, not pip if you're using Anaconda. Otherwise you're going to have to compile things, and that's no good on Windows.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed? If not, try using the exe files here: http://biopython.org/wiki/Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biopython recommends installing through `conda` if your python is also installed through `conda`. See [here](https://biopython.org/wiki/Packages).